# strange behaviour of \fontseries

Tags: fonts

In the following MWE, "Lorem ipsum" should be light, but you get the regular weight.

```
%\RequirePackage[2019/10/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
  
\begin{document}

\fontseries{l}\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\selectfont Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

The warning says:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/l/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.
```

Apparently, LaTeX tries OT1/cmr/l/n (which doesn't exist), substitutes OT1/cmr/m/n, and finally you get OT1/NotoSans-TLF/m/n.

If you use `\RequirePackage[2019/10/01]{latexrelease}` (this cancels the NFSS changes of LaTeX 2020-02-02), you get the light series as expected.

Further observations:

- If you ask for `\fontseries{sb}`, you get `b` instead.
- If you ask for `\fontseries{c}`, you get `m` instead.
- If you ask for `ul`, `el`, `m`, `b`, `eb` or `ub`, you get the requested font series. (This is very confusing because e. g. OT1/cmr/ul/n doesn't exist either)
- If you use `\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\fontseries{l}\selectfont Lorem ipsum` instead, you get the requested font series.
- The same problem occurs with other fonts.

---

**Update: This issue has been discussed [at GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/444) and classified as a bug. It will be fixed (along with other inconsistencies in the font selection mechanism) with the new LaTeX version 2021-06-01.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font attributes are changed in the order

```
\fontencoding
\fontfamily
\fontshape
\fontseries
\fontsize
```

So what happens with your input is that first the shape is changed to `l`, which Computer Modern hasn't, so it's substituted with the default `m`.

Using the proper order the output is as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\fontseries{l}\selectfont Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Most important is to have the family declaration at the beginning, because this will cause LaTeX to read the font definition file (if not already done) so the possible other attributes are known.

---

### Important update

With the forthcoming 2021-06-01 release of the LaTeX kernel, the issue should no longer be of a concern. On the other hand, keeping a semantic order of declarations when changing font is usually better.

Comment: Thanks. Is it documented somewhere that the order `\fontencoding\fontfamily\fontshape\fontseries\fontsize` is required? I cannot find such an advice e. g. in fntguide.pdf.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you want `\fontfamily` and `\fontencoding` before any of the others, in either order, and that series, shape and size come after, in any order. Please correct me if this is wrong?

Comment: @Davislor Better; `\fontencoding` first, then `\fontfamily` and the rest in no particular order, although sticking to a precise one is better.

Comment: @egreg Maybe the same order they’re displayed in, then: series, shape, size? That’s easiest to keep straight.

Comment: @egreg I’m sure there’s a good reason encoding comes first, but what is it? I sometimes need to switch both encoding and family to use a different language in PDFTeX, but I usually do that with `\substitutefont`.

Comment: @Davislor LaTeX wants to know what font definition file to load and this depends on the encoding. Possibly this order is not really necessary, but, again, sticking to a protocol is better.

Comment: You can't always follow such an order. If you have e.g. a quote set in semibold and use there some greek or \texttt then you are switching encoding and family after the series and that should work too.

Comment: @egreg Don’t those files have names like `t1cmr.fd`? Wouldn’t `\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{cmr}` and vice versa be equivalent?

Comment: With the new LaTeX version 2021-06-01, the order of font declarations should no longer matter. (See the note at the end of my edited answer.)

Answer (score 6):

The difference between the `ul` and the `l` series is that the LaTeX kernel has a rule for the `m/l` switch:

```
\DeclareFontSeriesChangeRule {m}{l}{l}{m}
```

This rule means that if `m` (first argument) is the current series, and `l` is requested (second argument) then `l` is tried (third argument) and if it doesn't exist the series falls back to `m` (fourth argument).

As egreg wrote, you are trying to change the series while `cmr` is still active, and so, as it has no `l`-series, `m` is forced.

You can get a similar effect for `ul` if you declare a rule for it too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{ \fontseries{ul}\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\selectfont Lorem ipsum }

\DeclareFontSeriesChangeRule {m}{ul}{ul}{m}

{ \fontseries{ul}\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\selectfont Lorem ipsum }

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can avoid the fallback to `m` by removing the fourth argument from the rule:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontSeriesChangeRule {m}{l}{l}{}
\begin{document}

\fontseries{l}\fontfamily{NotoSans-TLF}\selectfont Lorem ipsum 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568396/strange-behaviour-of-fontseries#comment1432845_568399) to egreg's answer (who wrote that one has to follow a specific order when changing font attributes), you wrote: "You can't always follow such an order. If you have e. g. [...] then you are switching encoding and family after the series and that should work too." Does that mean that my MWE reveals kind of a bug in LaTeX? (The MWE worked as intuitively expected before 2020-02-02.) Or do you agree with egreg that this is a user error?

Comment: no I don't think that there is a bug. Handling fonts with many series and weights  is rather challenging, and the default settings can't fit  to  every possible font combination. If you start to use a font with more than the normal series you will perhaps have to adjust the rules along the lines I showed in my example.

Comment: With the new LaTeX version 2021-06-01, the workaround described here is no longer necessary. (See the note at the end of my edited answer.)